# Using ajax to load a Django template containing Angularjs directives

Tags: angularjs, django

I'm attempting to use Angularjs's `$http` method to fetch given Django templates depending on the users selection, each of which includes Angular directives (`ng-if`) to further filter the content.

But while the templates are being inserted just fine, and I can see the directives when I check the html, the filtering isn't actually taking place. When I have the templates insert console logs they cannot find `$scope` variables that are accessible just above and below where the template is inserted.

A template I'm inserting looks like this:

```
    <div class="data_point_popup">
    {% if id in values_dict %}
        {% if values_dict|get_item:id|get_item:"not_applicable" == True %}
            n/a
        # ...
        {% else %}
            {% if id in definitions_dict %}
                {% if definitions_dict|get_item:id|get_item:"data_type" == "Integer" %}
                    {{ values_dict|get_item:id|get_item:"value"|floatformat:0 }}
                {% elif definitions_dict|get_item:id|get_item:"data_type" == "Currency" %}
                    <div class="currency eur" ng-if="Page.getCurrencySelection() === 'eur'">€{{ values_dict|get_item:id|get_item:"value_json"|get_item:"eur_value"|floatformat:2 }}</div>
                    <div class="currency gbp" ng-if="Page.getCurrencySelection() === 'gbp'">£{{ values_dict|get_item:id|get_item:"value_json"|get_item:"gbp_value"|floatformat:2 }}</div>
                    <div class="currency usd" ng-if="Page.getCurrencySelection() === 'usd'">${{ values_dict|get_item:id|get_item:"value_json"|get_item:"usd_value"|floatformat:2 }}</div>
                    <div class="currency base" ng-if="Page.getCurrencySelection() === 'base'">Base:{{ values_dict|get_item:id|get_item:"value_json"|get_item:"base_value"|floatformat:2 }}</div>
                    <script>console.log(Page.getCurrencySelection())</script>
               # ... 
            {% else %}
                <span style="color: red;">ERROR-NO_DEFINITION</span>
                <script>console.warn("Unable to find definition for data point {{ id }}.");</script>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        -
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

And my controller looks like:

```
function CompaniesDetailTabController($scope, $http, $sce, yearFrom, yearTo) {
// ...

    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        $("#accordion-"+$scope.data_point_section_id).accordion({
            onOpening: function() {
                $scope.currentYear = this.attr("data-accordion");
                $scope.accordions = {};
                    $scope.loading = true;
                    $scope.url = Urls["companies_detail_tab_with_year"]
                    $http({
                        "method": "GET",
                        "url": $scope.url
                    }).then(
                        function(response) {
                            $scope.loading = false;
                            $scope.accordions[$scope.currentYear] = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data);
                        },
                        function() {
                            $scope.accordions[$scope.currentYear] = $sce.trustAsHtml(Page.getGeneralError());
                            $scope.errorCallback();
                        },
                        function() {

                        }
                    );
            }
        });
    });

// ...

}
```

I'd like to know how I can insert the template and have the angular directives function?

Comment: I'm not sure you're using both AngularJS and Django the right way here. You should use one or the other to render the views, not both. Personally, I would use AngularJS to render the views and have Django serve the actual content, via JSON, that needs to be displayed inside those views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem did not have anything to do with Django templates in the end, it was a general problem with trying to insert html that contains Angular directives directly into the page. What I needed to do instead was to `$compile` the template before inserting it. Like this:

```
function(response) {
    var tab = $("div[data-tab='" + tabPath + "']");
    var template = angular.element(response.data);
    var link = $compile(template);
    var element = link($scope);
    tab.append(element);
 });
```